# change background-color for a tr on hover

Tags: css, hover, tr

I want to change the background-color for a tr on hover, is there a way to select the rows thats going to be affected by that?
At this point I'm using

```
tr:hover td{background:#EDEDED;}
```

But this changes the backcolor on every tr on my page.
Is there a way to make the changes only apply for a tr with example class="change_on_over"

Comment: The css selector is correct and should affect only the row that's being hovered right now, are you sure you don't have another table wrapping the one you want to change? Can you post the html code?

Comment: the solution posted under worked like a charm, I didn't fingure out that I had to define the class or id between the "tr"-prop and ":hover"

Comment: You don't if that's your only table, or if you define specify the correct table in the selector, i.e. if you have <table class="table-with-content"></table> you can do .table-with-content tr:hover td ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tr.change_on_over:hover td { background:#EDEDED; }
```

Comment: Like a charm :) Thank you, will be 'solved' in 10min, hehe, quick respond! Have a great day.